# Prerequisites for studying parametrized complexity

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, computability, approximation, parameterized-complexity

Which areas of CS/Math should one have mastered before diving into parametrized complexity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't come as a surprise, but you should definitely be familiar with algorithms and datastructures as well as complexity theory.

Two fundamental text books are downloadable for free, and you can probably find the answer to your question there:

- [*Marek Cygan, Fedor V. Fomin, Lukasz Kowalik, Daniel Lokshtanov, Daniel Marx, Marcin Pilipczuk, Michal Pilipczuk, and Saket Saurabh*, **Parameterized Algorithms**, Springer, 2015](http://parameterized-algorithms.mimuw.edu.pl/)
- [*Fedor V. Fomin, Daniel Lokshtanov, Saket Saurabh, and Meirav Zehavi*, **Kernelization. Theory of Parameterized Preprocessing**, Cambridge University Press, 2019.](https://kernelization.ii.uib.no/)

---

But to give my own short answer:

I think knowing some recursion theory (computation theory) is of benefit, since some of the levels in the parameterized hierarchies are based directly on Turing machine theory.

Most crucial is it that you have a good understanding of the complexity classes P and NP, and how to prove that algorithms are running in polynomial time, and how to prove that some problems are NP-complete.

Parameterized complexity is a fun area, enjoy your journey!

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I'm new here so I hope it's okay I already accepted it even though it's very recent. But it does answer my question fully.

Answer (score 1):

If you know Dynamic Programming, I would say you won't face a lot of difficulties studying it. You need to have basic knowledge of design and analysis of algorithms and dynamic programming at least. You can start with Tree-Width and Dynamic Programming. That would be a great place to start studying this topics. Then you will find one thing called 'Nice Tree Decomposition', which can be used to solve a NP-Hard problems using DP. Go through the 'Kernelization' book, it is a very good place to start. Then if you feel lost while studying parameterized algorithms for 3-Coloring, Steiner Tree, Independent set, you can search over the internet and you will find a lot of slides available online. I would suggest you to go through the slides of Daniel Marx titled 'Fixed Parameter Algorithms'.

Hope this helps